# Get @return from Annotation

Tags: php, reflection, annotations

I have this class

```
<?php
namespace Lorem\Ipsum\Do\Sor
use \Some\NameSpace\OfClass\SimpleClass;


class SimpleSecondClass {

    /**
    *
    * @return SimpleClass
    */
    public function someMethod(){
        return new SimpleClass();
    }

}
```

And i want get @return annotation from `someMethod` method with full `namespace ( \Some\NameSpace\OfClass\SimpleClass )`, without reading file contains this class. How can i do it?

Comment: The answer is [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php)

Comment: yes, i know about it - i know how can i get docBlock and parse it (for example with marcioAlmada/annotations library) . But i don't know how can get full namespace of @return value